# Project forked but .git removed. How to detect the forked version?

Tags: git

there is a fork of llvm/clang. This specific fork has removed the .git folder. Is there a way to detect, which specific version of the original project has been forked, so that changes can easily be spotted?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a simple way; the project doesn't have a changelog or similar file (non-code, changes often, easy to read). My suggestion would be to clone the official repo, then delete all files (leaving the `.git` folder) and copying the fork into the working copy.

That way, `git diff` will show you all the changes compared to the latest revision. The first thing would be to find all the files which are identical, sort them by date of the last commit. The latest one should be close to the point where the fork was made.

Answer (score 0):

This probably helps.

1. Fork the project on GitHub from https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang
2. Initiate a git repo in your local project.
3. Add github fork as a remote to your local repo.
4. `git fetch origin`
5. `git diff --stat origin/master`